# can we make a method as private in encapsulation in java?

Tags: java, methods, encapsulation

To achieve encapsulation we make members as private (variables) and use getter and setter methods for data hiding and that's how we achieve data hiding. So in the same way can we make a method as private and access it with getter or setter method ? (or is there any other way to do it)

Comment: Yes. That is possible.

Comment: You can call one private method from another public one if that is what you mean. But I can not imagine how would setting a method look like.

Comment: Do you want to return the method itself or the *result* of calling a method?

Comment: actually i want a method to be accessed as we access private variable that is we can't access private variables directly, so in the same way can we do it for methods?

Answer (score 1):

In Java private methods are the methods having private access modifier and are restricted to be accessed in the defining class only and are not visible in their child class due to which are not eligible for an override. However, we can define a method with the same name in the child class and could access in the parent class.
I don't think there can be getters and setters method for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly you can define a method as `private`, so that it can only be called (essentially) from other methods in the same class. This is a pretty common practice. For example, I might provide a method `getFoo()`, where the actual value of `foo` is not not simply an instance variable, but something derived by calculation using other (private) methods. To the user of the class, `getFoo()` returns some data called 'foo', but it can't see where it comes from -- whether it's stored, or derived, or some combination.

Comment: There are only two methods (no variables / no properties) in Employee class. One is public method GetEmployeeDetail() & other one is private GetSalary() method. GetSalary() method called inside GetEmployeeDetail() method. Now tell me please "Is this encapsulation". Or encapsulation means is only hiding the data variables. I'm confused.

Answer (score -1):

In your scenario, having a public method GetEmployeeDetail() and a private method GetSalary() within the Employee class can be considered a form of encapsulation.
By making GetSalary() private, you are encapsulating the salary-related logic within the class and exposing only the necessary details through the public method.

So, in summary, having methods that encapsulate functionality (both data and methods) within a class contributes to encapsulation in object-oriented programming.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).